# R string containing only one type of character

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to check if a string contain only one type of character

For example

```
INPUT: 

str = "AAAAB"
char = "A"

OUTPUT:

str contains only char = FALSE
```

With `grepl(char,str)` the result is TRUE but I want it to be FALSE.

Many thanks

Comment: You may need some special logic if your `str` is `""`. For instance, [m0nhawk's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25159415/452096) will output `TRUE` in this case (`!grepl("[^A]", "")`), which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `not` operator for regex, in your case this would be:

```
> !grepl("[^A]", "AAA")
[1] TRUE
> !grepl("[^A]", "AAAB")
[1] FALSE
```

With variables:

```
grepl(paste0("[^", char, "]"), srt)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check for a specific character (in `char`):

```
str <- "AAAAB"
char = "A"
all(unlist(strsplit(str, "")) == char)
#[1] FALSE

str <- "AAAA"
char = "A"
all(unlist(strsplit(str, "")) == char)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or, if you want to check if the string contains only one unique character (any one):

```
str <- "AAAAB"
length(unique(unlist(strsplit(str, "")))) == 1
#[1] FALSE

str = "AAAA"
length(unique(unlist(strsplit(str, "")))) == 1
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `charToRaw` and check if it is unique:

```
xx <- "AAAAB"
length(unique(charToRaw(xx))) ==1
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: This does not takes in count `char = "A"` as an input

Answer (score 3):

Using `gregexpr`

```
char = "A"

str = "AAAA"
length(unlist(gregexpr(char, str))) == nchar(str)
## [1] TRUE

str = "ABAAA"
length(unlist(gregexpr(char, str))) == nchar(str)
## [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `stri_count` from the "stringi" package, like this:

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_fixed(str, char) == nchar(str)
# [1] FALSE
```